# Facing an IndexError for rotating a list

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have just started programming and started solving problems. During my practice, I came across this problem and cannot understand why my code is not working.
So the task is to cyclically rotate the array consisting of N elements, clockwise by K.

**Example 1:**
5  —Value of N

{10, 20, 30, 40, 50}  —Element of Arr[ ]

2  —–Value of K

**Output :**
40 50 10 20 30

I attempted to solve it by this Python 3 code:

```
Arr=[]
Arr2=[]
N=int(input("Enter the number of elements:"))
k=int(input())
if (k>N):
  k=k%N

for i in range (0,N):
  a=input()
  Arr.append(a)

for i in range (0,N):
  if ((i+k)<N):
    Arr2[i+k]=Arr[I]
else:
    Arr2[i+k-N]=Arr[I]
print (Arr2)
```

It is showing an IndexError for arr2[i+k] even though it should never go to that index as there is the condition **(i+k<N)**.
Please can someone explain it to me? Thanks

Comment: Can you use multiple loops? I would append elements from K to N, then from 0 to K to the new list. Your `Arr2` is empty, so there is no `(i+k)`th index.

Comment: use `(i+k)%N` whatever the value of i+k, that will make sure you stay within bounds

Comment: A simpler approach would be to cut and stitch the list with `a[k+1:] + a[:k+1]`, or use `collections.deque` and just use its `rotate` method.

Answer (score 1):

Well you have to first define Arr2 as a list with a fixed size. Something like this:

```
Arr2 = [0]*N
```

which gives you an output of Arr2 to be:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Then, it is safe to include your final snippet of code:

```
for i in range (0,N):
  if ((i+k)<N):
    Arr2[i+k]=Arr[i]
else:
    Arr2[i+k-N]=Arr[i]
print (Arr2)
```

Comment: Can you please accept my answer as it works for you?(Tick it to be green)

Answer (score 1):

Actually Arr2 has no any elements. So you cannot assign a value to if there nothing at the given index.

```
Arr2[i+k]=Arr[I]
```

Here have to define i+k index in the Arr2.

If it is works for you you try this one but this is temporary solution not the perfect way.

```
Arr2 = []

for i in range(1000):
  Arr2.append(0)

print(len(a))
```

you can change inside of range function. I can't get your mathematically representation about that but you can change that part with your maximum index formula of your problem.